# Finding lychrel numbers under 10000, logic seems correct but wrong answer?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String numstr="";
    int lychrel=0;
    int sum=0;
    int iterations=0;

for(int num=10;num<10000;num++){
    sum=num;
    iterations=1;
    numstr=sum+reverse(sum)+""; 
    while((isPalyndrom(numstr)==false)&&iterations<50){
        sum=sum+reverse(sum);
        numstr=sum+"";
        iterations++;
    }

if (iterations==50)
    lychrel++;
}
System.out.println(lychrel);
}//End of main
```

The methods reverse and isPalyndrom are 100% correct , but there's something about sum , when I print it out , some negative large numbers appear which is weird . 
The final answer of lychrels that is being printed after the execution is 553 ,which is wrong.

Comment: "some negative large numbers appear which is weird" You're experiencing overflow. Try using `long` or `BigInteger`.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a lot :) I changed the variables in the reverse method from int to long and the final answer is 249 now .